# Contenerized expressjs app can't access mongo container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

So, I have created an app using Express.js + Typescript + mongoose and this docker-compose for development:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        container_name: selfapi
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            - db
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            target: development
        ports:
            - ${PORT}:${PORT}
        environment:
            MONGODB_URL: ${MONGODB_URL}
            NODE_ENV: development
            AUTH_TOKEN: ${AUTH_TOKEN}
        volumes:
            - ./src/:/home/node/app/src
            - ./tests/:/home/node/app/tests
            - web_nodemodules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    db:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo:5.0.4
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_ROOT_USERNAME}
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - mongodb_data:/data/db/
            - mongodb_configdb:/data/configdb/
    mongo-express:
        container_name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express:0.54.0
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGODB_ROOT_USERNAME}
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: db
            ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: ${MONGO_EXPRESS_USERNAME}
            ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_EXPRESS_PASSWORD}
volumes:
    web_nodemodules:
    mongodb_data:
    mongodb_configdb:
```

Following that and assuming that both username and password for mongodb are `root`, we can get to the database url `mongodb://root:root@db:27017` for any service within the compose, and `mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017` for the host machine.

In my app, I connect to database this way:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const connectMongoDb = async () => {
    try {
        return await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL as string);
    } catch {
        return process.exit(1);
    }
};
```

But it *only* works if I don't add any database name to the url, so the url can't be something like `mongodb://root:root@db:27017/myDatabase`.

When I put only the raw mongodb url, and use the command `ts-node-dev --poll --respawn --transpile-only --inspect -- ./src/index.ts`, everything works fine as you will see below:
API:
[image: api container]
[image: api localhost]

But when I add something to my mongodb using the express app, it goes to a database called `test`, as you can see here in the mongo-express:
[image: test db]
[image: projects collection]

Now, let's say I don't want that to happen, intead, I want that the collection `projects` goes to a database calles `MyApp`, so I'd put it in the db url, becoming: `mongodb://root:root@db:27017/MyApp`. Following mongodb docs, if the database doesn't exist, it creates on first insertion, but this is what happens:

.env
[image: .env]

API:
[image: second api container]
Apparently it is working, right? But no, take a look how it is on browser when I access the API:
[image: not working]
"This page is not working"
"No data was sent by localhost"

That is happening *just because* I added the name I wanted that my database to have.

How can I fix that, changing the name, because it's REALLY annoying that all my data goes to a database calles `TEST`...

PS.: When my app is in a production environment, the url WITH the database name works, but the url is from mongodb Atlas, so it is something like this: `mongodb+srv://test:test@db1.mongodb.net/GithubProjects?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, as you can see, the database name is `GithubProjects`, and it works.

Comment: Try using `mongodb://root:root@db:27017/myDatabase?authSource=admin`

Comment: Hey @Joe thanks for the help. Ok, I have no idea how and why it worked, but it did. Also, there is no `test` dabatase, why? I was reading mongodb docs, and it is saying that the default database name is only `db`, shouldn't it be used in my case instead of `test`?

Comment: When you specify a database name in the connection string, it is assumed the credential you are using was created in that database, unless you also specify `authSource`.